# Where to get an CUDA/GPU enabled version of the HPL benchmark?

Tags: benchmark, cuda

After setting up a new compute server for my research group I need to evaluate the overall performance of this machine, including both Tesla cards. I found some information about a CUDA enabled version of Linpack and how it is used, but no download links for the software.

So the problem is, where to get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real CUDA-enabled HPL benchmark, which is used for the TOP500 list too. Is available direcly from NVidia after registration. It is only accessible for members of the 
["CUDA Registered Developer Program"](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cuda-registered-developer-program).